# drag and drop form tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to drag and drop image from one place to another (instead of image I am trying to drag and drop the form elemnt which contains the image tag)

so in my drag event I am taking that form tag in global variable

```
 this.on("dragstart", function (event) {

            formReplaced = $(event.target).closest('form');

        });
```

and in my drop event I am trying to replace the drop form element.

```
  this.on("drop", function (event) {

            var x = $(event.target).closest('form')
            x.parentNode.removeChild(x);
            x.parentNode.append(formReplaced)
       });
```

its not working as expected. the form elemnt contains image, it should change on drag and drop. what I am doing wrong?